# How many days after interview to follow up?

Tags: interviewing, follow-up

I am kind of on a gas burner in my current job and would like to find another option. Interview was 3 days back excluding the weekend in between. How many days after is best to follow up about the position with the recruiter?

Comment: Did the interviewer or recruiter give you any estimate as to when they would follow up with you?

Comment: Nope, they did not. I was an idiot and forgot to ask them about the next steps myself.

Comment: That'll at least give you something to ask about when you make the call.

Comment: Is the recruiter an external or internal recruiter? (Is the recruiter employed by the company?0

Comment: Annedoct: I received a call from Bob and my first reaction was: "Bob? From where?". It was a CEO from a startup, he interviewed me (a dozen weeks ago) and was finally calling me to say: "good news! You are in!" At this point, all I can say was "a dozen weeks? Seriously?"

Answer (score 1):

Usually when they're looking for someone to fill a new position, it is common to interview at least a handful of people, and their availability might influence on how long this takes.

If I were you, I would wait until the end of the week or next Monday to ask about it, but bear in mind that this will not raise your chances of being hired and depending on how you approach him, it could been seen as an act of desperation or insecurity.

Answer (score 1):

Often your best bet is to land another interview, which gives you an excuse to call the original interviewer up and say "I'm interviewing for an opportunity at another company on [day] - Can you tell me whether you're still considering me as a candidate for [role] for which I interviewed on [date]?" If they say yes, you get the opportunity to ask follow up questions like "Great! Can you tell me when I can expect to hear from you?"

All that being said, I don't think you're likely to create problems for yourself if you simply call them and say "I neglected to ask you when I could expect to hear from you again regarding the results of my interview and next steps. Would you mind sharing that information, so that I don't accept another opportunity before you get a chance to respond?"

Note: If they say something like 'well, we're no longer considering you for the role', you have a huge opportunity to humbly seek some feedback for things you might do differently in future interviews. Rather than asking "what did I do wrong?" or "what didn't you like?", use your best I-really-just-want-to-learn voice and ask "Do you have any suggestions for things I might do differently to enhance my interviews at other employers?" You could get some very rare and valuable feedback that way.